# How can I read a file and place the content into a struct (using c)?

Tags: c, file, struct

What I want is to understand how I can take the contents of a file and place them inside a struct.

The file I'm working with (for testing purposes) has this content inside:

```
Pedro Nuno;10;15000,000000;2016;5;55;68;71;22
```

And I want to place it into this struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    char *nome;
    int numero;
    float salario;
    int inicio_contrato;
    int anos_contrato;
    int forca_defesa;
    int forca_medio;
    int forca_avancado;
    int forca_guardaredes;
} jogadores;
```

How can I go about doing it? Are those semicolons necessary, or should I remove them? Do I have any major issues with the struct itself?

I mainly want the first question answered, but, if possible, I would also like your opinion on anythig you might consider important for me to understand.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: C is a very low-level language. It doesn't even really have a string type and its convenient manipulations. You have to do the hard work of finding the semicolons, converting the digits between them to numbers, allocating memory for the name, and copying all the info into the structure, yourself. There are some library functions that might help, like `sscanf()`.

Comment: Don't remove the semicolons, they are helpful. You can use something like `sscanf(input_line, "%s;%d;%f;%d;", nome, &numero, &salario, &inicio_contrato);`, just an example for the first three fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution, however, I had to modify your example so that the point and not the comma is used for the floating point number:

```
Pedro Nuno;10;15000.000000;2016;5;55;68;71;22
```

Here's the sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h> // for input/output

#define BUFSIZE 1024
#define NAMESIZE 100

// this is your struct
typedef struct
{
    char *nome;
    int numero;
    float salario;
    int inicio_contrato;
    int anos_contrato;
    int forca_defesa;
    int forca_medio;
    int forca_avancado;
    int forca_guardaredes;
} jogadores;

int main()
{
    char buf[BUFSIZE], name[NAMESIZE], c;
    int i;

    // the name is handled seperately
    for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != ';' && i < NAMESIZE - 1; i++) {
        name[i] = c;
    }
    name[i] = 0; // terminate the string

    // the rest of the line is read into a buffer
    for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != EOF && i < BUFSIZE - 1; i++) {
        buf[i] = c;
    }
    buf[i] = 0; // terminate the string

    // the struct is created and the name is copied into the struct
    jogadores entry;
    entry.nome = name;

    // the numbers of the remaining line are read in
    sscanf(buf, "%d;%f;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;%d;",
        &entry.numero, &entry.salario, &entry.inicio_contrato,
        &entry.anos_contrato, &entry.forca_defesa, &entry.forca_medio,
        &entry.forca_avancado, &entry.forca_guardaredes);

    // the whole struct is printed
    printf("%s\n%d\n%f\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n",
        entry.nome, entry.numero, entry.salario, entry.inicio_contrato,
        entry.anos_contrato, entry.forca_defesa, entry.forca_medio,
        entry.forca_avancado, entry.forca_guardaredes);

    return 0; // tell the caller that everything went fine
}
```

Comment: In theory, `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` should allow you to use the `.` and Ertas10 (the OP) to use `,` for the decimal point.

Comment: Managing the memory for the name is fiddly.  It would be feasible to use `%99[^;]` to read up to 99 characters (leaving the hundredth for the trailing null) into a suitable string — `name` in your code.  So you could simply read the whole line with standard C [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or POSIX [`readline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readline.html), and then scan all the information into the structure at once.

Comment: You might be able to use the `m` modifier to POSIX [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html) too, with appropriate other changes.

Comment: Thank you very much dude! I had to change just a few things, but it works perfectly now!